# org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I just want to perform one to one mapping in my hibernate entity. I am facing a strange problem and i searched a lot on google but not found any solution. Below are my entity and classes.

**JobAlertsEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job_alerts")
public class JobAlertsEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "job_id")
    private int job_id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int user_id;

    @Column(name = "sent_date")
    private String sent_date;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="job_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private JobsEntity jobsEntity;
```

**JobsEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employers_job")
public class JobsEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "job_id")
    private int job_id;

    @Column(name = "emp_name")
    private String emp_name;

    @Column(name = "designation")
    private String designation;

    @Column(name = "skills")
    private String skills;

    @Column(name = "job_description")
    private String job_description;

    @Column(name = "location")
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "experience")
    private String experience;

    @Column(name = "exp_from")
    private String exp_from;

    @Column(name = "exp_to")
    private String exp_to;

    @Column(name = "ctc")
    private String ctc;

    @Column(name = "func_area")
    private String func_area;

    @Column(name = "industry")
    private String industry;

    @Column(name = "postgrad")
    private String postgrad;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "contactno")
    private String contactno;

    @Column(name = "caddress")
    private String caddress;

    @Column(name = "date_of_posting")
    private String date_of_posting;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "job_expire_date")
    private String job_expire_date;

    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String company_name;

    @Column(name = "company_desc")
    private String company_desc;

    @Column(name = "job_viewed")
    private String job_viewed;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
```

here is my code :-

```
public List<Jobs> getAllJobAlerts(String jobseeker_id) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        Session session = null;
        List<Jobs> alerts = null;

        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();           

            List<JobAlertsEntity> jobs_data = (List<JobAlertsEntity>) session.createQuery("from JobAlertsEntity je where je.user_id = "+jobseeker_id+"").list();            


            if(jobs_data != null) {
                for(Iterator data = jobs_data.iterator(); data.hasNext();) {
                    JobAlertsEntity je = (JobAlertsEntity) data.next();
                    JobsEntity jo = je.getJobsEntity();

                    Jobs job = new Jobs();

                    job.setEmp_name(jo.getEmp_name());

                    alerts.add(job);
                }
            }           

            transaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }
        return alerts;
    }
```

I am getting every time this exception :-

```
*org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1284)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.jobsdhamaka.serviceimpl.JobAlertsServiceImpl.getAllJobAlerts(JobAlertsServiceImpl.java:18)
    org.jobsdhamaka.serviceimpl.JobAlertsServiceImpl.getAllJobAlerts(JobAlertsServiceImpl.java:18)
    org.jobsdhamaka.serviceimpl.JobAlertsServiceImpl.getAllJobAlerts(JobAlertsServiceImpl.java:18)
    org.jobsdhamaka.serviceimpl.JobAlertsServiceImpl.getAllJobAlerts(JobAlertsServiceImpl.java:18)*
```

please suggest me what am i doing wrong in my code.

Comment: Where is the line 18 ?

Comment: This is a long shot but I had the same exception when I wasn't adding any authorities to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.